# How do I get parameter values for SQL Server query in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

I'm trying to analyze a deadlock in SQL Server 2008 profiler. I know how to find the offending sql queries, but the collected queries do not include parameter values.

I other words I can see something like this:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = @id
```

But what I would like to see is this:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 12345
```

I guess there are some additional events or Columns I need to collect in the profiler, but I don't know which. I am currently using the "TSQL_LOCKS" template.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adrian

Disclaimer: I've asked a similar question before, but I guess it was too specific, which is why I got no replies. I'm starting another attempt with this one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you need the RPC:Completed event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175543.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The Profiler will contain the parameter values in the [RPC:Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175543.aspx)/[RPC:Starting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175927.aspx) events. But you already got replies telling you this.

What I want to add is that is very little need to know the parameter run-time values in order to analyze a deadlock graph. First, because if 'users' is involved in the deadlock, the deadlock graph itself will give away what @id is the conflict, if the conflict is on a key. Second, more importantly, for a deadlock scenario is irrelevant the exact keys that are involved. Is not like a deadlock happens because one deletes user with id 123 but will not happen when it deletes user 321.

If you decided to ask on SO in the first place, I think the best would be to post the actual deadlock graph and let the community have a look at it. There are many here that can answer quite a few questions just from the deadlock graph XML.

Comment: BTW, if you do decide to post the whole graph, not just half (?), please, do post the actual deadlock graph, not a picture of it. ie. the XML of the deadlock event, not a screenshot of the rendered image. There is a LOT of information that gets lost during rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think there is a misunderstanding. The picture I linked to in my other post is not from my computer. I got it from a tutorial on how to use the SQL server profiler. It shows parameter values in the graph tooltip, whereas my own graph's tooltips only include the queries, but no parameter values. Which is why I posted my question.

Comment: @Adrian: always look inside the XML for analysis. The graphical rendering in SSMS is just to get a quick glance. Save the event (right click on it) and then open the saved file as ordinary XML.

Answer (score 1):

Start a trace with the following events having all checkboxes checked:

```
SQL: BatchCompleted
SQL: BatchStarting
Deadlock graph
Lock:Deadlock
Lock:Deadlock chain
```

After the deadlock occurs, stop the trace, then click on the deadlock graph event class.

This should give you a good idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that already. The problem is that the deadlock graph does not contain parameter values, just the query as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952830/how-do-i-get-parameter-values-for-sql-server-query-in-sql-server-profiler

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a stored procedure (which it looks like you are) or Hibernate/NHibernate you might need to turn on the Stored Procedures starting event (SP:StmtStarting) and RPC:Starting event. This will show the parameters in it's own line after the query.

Something like:

SP:StmtStarting    DELETE FROM users WHERE id = @id

RPC:Starting       exec sp_execute 12345

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I wasn't using a SP in this case, but it's still good to know.