# How to see variable values in SQL Profiler when Trigger fires?

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-profiler

I am creating an "After Update" Trigger on a SQL Server 2008 table. The trigger fires just fine but one of the values it's updating in another table isn't correct. I am looking at a trace in SQL Profiler, but I can't see my variable's values in there.

I read [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952830/how-do-i-get-parameter-values-for-sql-server-query-in-sql-server-profiler) and so added the RPC: Completed Event to my trace, but there were not instances of that event in my trace for some reason. That is, I see it at other places in the trace but not where my trigger is firing.

Just to (hopefully) be clear, my trigger is EXECUTING an SP like this:

```
EXEC SP_UpdateSomeStuff @variable1, @variable2
```

... and that's all that I see in the trace. What I wish to see is:

```
EXEC SP_UpdateSomeStuff @variable1 = 111, @variable2 = 222
```

... but I can't figure out which events to add to get this. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"RPC" stands for "Remote Procedure Call" -- generally, queries submitted "from outside" to SQL Server. Trigger events are anything but outside calls, which should be why you are not seeing them in Profiler.

I suspect that you won't be able to see your paremeter values via SQL Profiler. Can you temporarily put in debugging code `(insert DebugTable values (Wvariable1, etc.)`, such that the value you are working with get logged somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I see now. I will have to try that insert to debug idea. Thanks!