# How to see stored proc/functions within stored proc in profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler

I hope this question is not a duplicate as I searched for it and didn't see many meaningful answers.

Is it possible using profiler to see the calls being done for procedure and functions within a procedure?

I am currently using a simple

```
select 'P1', @P1
select 'P2', @P2
proc Y(@P1,@P2,@P3 OUTPUT)
select @P3
```

to solve this issue, which gets quite tiresome especially when some procs take in like 20 parameters and output about 6 others.

Also, I don't want to see the function in profiler like this:

```
Y(@P1,@P2,@P3 OUTPUT)
```

But rather would see it with inline values like

```
Y(5,15,0)
```

So is that possible using just the built-in profiler with SQL Server (2014)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.    It would be nice though.

Comment: Have a look at the [RPC: Starting and RPC:Completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952830/how-do-i-get-parameter-values-for-sql-server-query-in-sql-server-profiler) events