# SQL Server profiler trace not showing parameter values

Tags: sql-server, query-analyzer

I've searched for solutions on this but haven't found anything that works for me yet. I'm successfully using **SQL Server Profiler** to trace my calls to procedures and queries for one instance of **SQL Server**. It's very handy because I can see the calls to the procedures, including the values being passed in the parameters.

I am trying to do the same thing using a different instance of SQL Server and instead of seeing the values being passed in parameters, I'm seeing `@parametername`. I'm using the same install of **SQL Server Profiler** and I think I'm selecting the same trace settings (although for some reason the interface looks different when I connect to different instances).

Is there a setting  inherent to the database instance itself that can be causing this or is it somehow a problem with my trace setup? I do have `RPC:Completed` checked. I really need to be able to see those values.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: show this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952890/1998051

Comment: Thanks Hamed, I saw that link before. I also tried SQL: BatchCompleted
SQL: BatchStarting
SP:StmtStarting but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably don't have the same Events selected on the one **SQL Instance**, than on the other.

To achieve this, click on the **Event Selection** as can be seen below:

[image]

After selecting this, click on **Show all events** as can be seen below:

[image]

Compare the **Event Selection** with the one on the other `Instance`, then you'll be able to see.

Hope this helps.